# mesh.posotions and new Point3D(x,y,z) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, three.js

```
private void BuildVertices(double x, double y, double len) {
  if (len > 0.002) {
    mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(x, y + len, -len));
    mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(x - len, y - len, -len));
    mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(x + len, y - len, -len));
    len *= 0.5;
    BuildVertices(x, y + len, len);
    BuildVertices(x - len, y - len, len);
    BuildVertices(x + len, y - len, len);
  }
}
```

If I want to convert it to javascript
What is the `mesh`, and how to use it in javascript, and also what is`mesh.positions`, `mesh.positions.add`, `new Point3D(x, y, z)`

I would love some suggestions of how?

Here is a link to what this code does
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAEZW.gif

Comment: It is Java or C#

Comment: can you be specific

Comment: It's most likely C#.

Comment: any suggestion of how I would convert it to javascript

Comment: @JigSaw No, because the context is missing.  Since your question has the tag [tag:three.js], I suggest to create a [`BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry)

Comment: here is a link of what this code do.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAEZW.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is for the #C language and is a Unity game engine.
JavaScript used to support this engine but now it does not.
Mesh is a class that has spatial coordinate information.

In general, and as a conclusion, this code snippet cannot be converted to JavaScript because it is not currently supported